# Apple Maps takes me to the wrong home address

Tags: ios, maps

I live at 53 5th Street in Springfield, but on my 4S Apple Maps, when I ask it to take me home, keeps taking me to 53th 5th Street in Shelbyville. Note, addresses are obviously made-up but I do live on a street with an ordinal number in it, which I think may be revelant. Also possibly relevant is that I work in Shelbyville, but I've tried erasing my work address entirely from my contact, and this still happens; perhaps because I am currently in Shelbyville.

Things I've tried:

- Replacing "5th St" with another street name (without a number in it) that also appears in both towns. Surprise! It took me to that address in neigboring Brockway! But subsequent results took me to Springfield or Brockway, seemingly at random.
- Spelling out 5th as Fifth. That took me to a street in a random town in a neighboring state.
- Returning Fifth to 5th. It took me home! But only the first time; the second time I tried it it was back to Shelbyville, consistently.

Now, I know Apple Maps is still something of a joke, and perhaps the answer is to just use another mapping tool. This behaviour was present in iOS 6 as well, so it's not new, and I have used other tools. But I would love to use Siri to get directions home and the integration of Maps into the lock screen in iOS 7 is pretty sweet. But maybe it's just not for me... any thoughts?

Comment: 53 5th St Springfield, OH 45504, USA! but on Google maps :)

Comment: Try using the (,) after 53

Comment: Did you try with just the zip code instead of the city?

Comment: With or without the comma, same effect. Ditto for using just ZIP (my prior attempts had city, state, ZIP).

Comment: Does maps have another hit for "home" in the place it sends you? Are you being specific asking for "to my home" or do you just say "get me directions home"